# getting "pygpu was configured but could not be imported" error while trying with OpenCL+Theano on AMD Radeon

Tags: opencl, theano, amd-gpu

I have followed the instructions from this:

https://gist.github.com/jarutis/ff28bca8cfb9ce0c8b1a

But then when I tried : `THEANO_FLAGS=device=opencl0:0 python test.py`
on the test file I am getting error:

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mesayantan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>

    import pygpu

  File "/usr/src/gtest/clBLAS/build/libgpuarray/pygpu/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>

    from . import gpuarray, elemwise, reduction
  File "/usr/src/gtest/clBLAS/build/libgpuarray/pygpu/elemwise.py", line 3, in <module>

    from .dtypes import dtype_to_ctype, get_common_dtype
  File "/usr/src/gtest/clBLAS/build/libgpuarray/pygpu/dtypes.py", line 6, in <module>

    from . import gpuarray
ImportError: cannot import name gpuarray
```

I do not have a good idea. I am using all these for the first time. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this issue with the step-by-step installation given in the lipgpuarray website!

Download

```
git clone https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray.git
cd libgpuarray
```

Install `libgpuarray`

```
# extract or clone the source to <dir>
cd <dir> 
mkdir Build
cd Build
# you can pass -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/somewhere to install to an alternate location
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release # or Debug if you are investigating a crash
make
make install
cd ..
```

Install `pygpu`

```
# This must be done after libgpuarray is installed as per instructions above.
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Source:
http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html

This worked for me!
Good Luck

Comment: The line `python setup.py build` is slightly different if you specify a prefix during cmake. The link provides the correct line in this context.

Answer (score 5):

Installing the `blas` library seems enough. I'm doing tests for the same problem.

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS.git
cd clBLAS/
mkdir build
cd build/
sudo apt-cache search openblas
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack3gf liblapack-doc liblapack-dev
cmake ../src
make
sudo make install
```

And after that

```
git clone https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray.git
cd libgpuarray
mkdir Build
cd Build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install cython
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git
```

Building and Installing with regard to `python3`

```
python3 setup.py build
sudo -H python3 setup.py install
```

I hope it can help you. Now just the dev version of `theano` is missing for me.