# How to investigate ImportError: DLL load failed error

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, theano

Is there any common way for investigation of such errors when import module in python on Windows? DependencyWalker does not help much.

For example I'm having problem now with Theano and Anaconda Python on Windows 8.1. For some reason python can't load DLL for `libgpuarray` and I want to know how I can investigate this.

Here is how error looks like.

```
C:\Users\test>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import theano
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.6 or higher required)
NoneType: None
>>> import pygpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygpu\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import gpuarray, elemwise, reduction
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is Process Monitor log:

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"18:54:04,6207404","python.exe","904","RegQueryKey","HKCU","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"18:54:04,6207581","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\Modules\pygpu","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6207938","python.exe","904","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"18:54:04,6208037","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\Modules\pygpu","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6216013","python.exe","904","RegQueryKey","HKCU","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"18:54:04,6216203","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\Modules\pygpu.gpuarray","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6216495","python.exe","904","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"18:54:04,6216628","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\Modules\pygpu.gpuarray","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6222903","python.exe","904","Load Image","C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pygpu\gpuarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd","SUCCESS","Image Base: 0x7ff90ddc0000, Image Size: 0x50000"
"18:54:04,6223757","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6223996","python.exe","904","RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\PreferExternalManifest","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 20"
"18:54:04,6224148","python.exe","904","RegCloseKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide","SUCCESS",""
"18:54:04,6228026","python.exe","904","Load Image","C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\Library\bin\gpuarray.dll","SUCCESS","Image Base: 0x7ff90dd80000, Image Size: 0x34000"
"18:54:04,6228964","python.exe","904","RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"18:54:04,6229175","python.exe","904","RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\PreferExternalManifest","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 20"
"18:54:04,6229324","python.exe","904","RegCloseKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide","SUCCESS",""
```

So it looks like DLL was found and loaded into process space.

Comment: You can follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297995/getting-pygpu-was-configured-but-could-not-be-imported-error-while-trying-with

Comment: I have libgpuarray installed and I want to investigate why python can't find it. Also I use Windows not Linux.

Comment: How did you install `Theano`...did you use the `conda` package?

Comment: Yes, installed with conda.

Comment: Using process monitor to check which dll is not found is good.