# How I use NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to set up a Neural Composer from [Generating Songs With Neural Networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWxfnNXlVy8&t), and I am having some problems with `theano`.

I am completely new to coding and I probably shouldn't be trying to do something so complex for my lack knowledge, so sorry if this has really simple answer.

I have tried re-installing packages and updating them and also checking if I have anything missing.

I am trying to run train.py from [HackerPoet](https://github.com/HackerPoet/Composer) to train it on my own midi files.

```
C:\Users\natea\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/natea/Desktop/Composer-master/Composer-master/train.py

Loading Keras...
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.7 or higher required)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\natea\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import pygpu
ImportError: No module named pygpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/natea/Desktop/Composer-master/Composer-master/train.py", line 60, in <module>
import keras
ImportError: No module named keras
Theano Version: 1.0.4

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a error of not getting the right package to work with.

I am assuming you installed or updated the packages using `pip`, which doesn't always install packages exactly what you need.

From what I have learned,  the version of `pygpu` installed has to be compatible with the stable `Theano` but `pip` only installs the current stable release which may or may not be compatible with the installed `pygpu`.

Try reinstalling `libgpuarray` of `theano` from [@tobnic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338235/5668215) about the same issue.

Also refer [this issue](https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/issues/536) for the below "workaround"..

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```